# Returning the result of a UIAlert to a delegate method

Tags: swift

Is it possible, with a UIAlert, to return what the user selected to a delegate method? If so, how?

I'd prefer not to change the delegate method or stop using UIAlert, if such a solution exists. Though *all help and ideas are appreciated.*

### Delegate Protocol

```
protocol RouteManagerDelegate {
     //behaves like textFieldShouldEndEditing
     func routeShouldUpdateUnfinished() -> Bool
}
```

### My Current Attempt at Implementation

```
extension MyController : RouteManagerDelegate {
     func routeShouldUpdateUnfinished() -> Bool {
          var response = false

          //make Alert
          let confirmationAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Current Route is Unfinished", message: "Do you want to continue?", preferredStyle: .alert)
          //add Yes or No options
          confirmationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .destructive) { _ in
               response = true
          })
          confirmationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel)
                
          self.present(confirmationAlert, animated: true)

          return response
     }
}
```

This doesn't work because UIAlert behaves asynchronously. The function simply returns `false` every time.

But you can clearly see the intent:
If the user selects 'Yes' (continue), then `routeShouldUpdateUnfinished` should `return true`.

Comment: You already know that `UIAlert` is asynchronous. The only way to convert asynchronicity to synchronicity is to wait for the result. This is okey if the method is *never* called from the main thread. However, ideally the method should be asynchronous and have a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone finds themselves in this esoteric position:

I wanted to do as Ramden suggested, but also didn't want to expose a function that other classes should never use (except in this scenario).

I ended up using a default implementation for my delegate method (defined in an extension of my protocol) and a `static fileprivate` method to handle the result of my delegate method returning true.

Now the fileprivate 'handler' method isn't exposed but I can also use a UIAlert. This has flaws but works. Implementation below, if ever it's useful to someone.

```
protocol RouteManagerDelegate {
     func routeShouldUpdateUnfinished() -> Bool
}

extension RouteManagerDelegate { //default implementations of delegate protocol
    func routeShouldUpdateUnfinished() -> Bool {
        if let delegate = self as? UIViewController {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Wait!", message: "Do you want to continue?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            confirmationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .destructive) { _ in
                RouteManager.handleRouteChangedUnfinished() //the 'handler' function
            })
            confirmationAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel))
            
            delegate.present(confirmationAlert, animated: true)
        }
        
        return false
    }
}

struct RouteManager {
     func myFunc() {
          ...
          if delegate?.routeShouldUpdateUnfinished() ?? true {
              RouteManager.handleRouteChangedUnfinished() //the 'handler' function
          }
          ...
     }

    static fileprivate func handleRouteChangedUnfinished() { //don't want to expose this
        //Notify the Database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the provided code looks like the delegate method is being understood wrong. To help you out a little, here a little diagram:

[image]

The delegate pattern is used to communicate from child to parent.
In your solution this could look like:

1. Parent implements delegate pattern with function

   func routeShouldUpdateUnfinished(result: bool) { ... }
2. When parent sets child up the parent calls

   child.delegate = self
3. The alert inside child calls

   delegate.routeShouldUpdateUnfinished(true)
4. The parent handles the code

Comment: Think of [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn). Imagine you wanted to confirm that the user really wants to return from the text field with a UIAlert. You would pass their choice as a boolean to`textFieldShouldReturn` (or at least that's the same situation I'm facing here). Am I wrong to be doing it this way?

Comment: Maybe, at least the illustrated code could indicate that. Without knowing your code exactly: the delegate for a UITextField is the view controller. In those delegate methods (when the user is leaving the field) you would show the alert probably. If the user says "cancel" you just dismiss the alert. If not (user says "Yes") you would call the consequence of yes inside the alert itself, for example: dismissKeyboardAndGoToNextField()

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. Hopefully my comment was helpful. Your last comment pushed me in the right direction so I can use an alert and keep the interface I want. Thanks!